# .htaccess rewrite rule remove everything after RK=0/RS=

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website that is getting a lot of requests for pages that don't exist.

All the requests are based on an existing page, but have `RK=0/RS=` plus a random string of characters at the end.

For example, the request is:

```
www.domain.com/folder/article/RK=0/RS=M9j32OWsFAC_u8I6a0xOMjYKU_Q-
```

but the page `www.domain.com/folder/article` does exist.

I would like to use `htaccess` to say:

> if `RK=0/RS=` exists, remove it and everything after

but haven't been able to get it working.

All the `htaccess` rules talking about removing query strings, but I'm guessing because this doesn't have a `?` it's not a query.

Could someone help me understand how to do this?

Comment: I've seen a lot of this traffic, too. Every originating IP address I've looked at has been from some hosting company, so I'm assuming this is some probe of some sort being launched from a botnet of compromised servers.

Comment: A duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24763239/2157640

Comment: A related one: [Strange entry in access log containing /RS= @ Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/58871/32372)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(folder/article/)RK=0/RS= /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks - that looks so simple it's embarrassing. I made a slight change so it'll work in all directories/paths, something I didnt mention)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)RK=0/RS= /$1 [L,NC,R=301]

I'm truly stumped to know what is making these requests - I suspect something malicious, so redirecting makes me feel more comfortable.

Answer (score 4):

Someone found where this mess is coming from.
http://xenforo.com/community/threads/server-logs-with-rk-0-rs-2-i-now-know-what-these-are.73853/

It looks like actually NOT malicious, it's something broken with Yahoo rewrites that create URLs that point to pages that don't exist.
The demo described on xenforo does replicate it, and the pattern of the URLS that Yahoo is producing:

```
http://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=A0SO810GVXBTMyYAHoxLBQx./RV=2/RE=1399899526/RO=10/RU=http%3a%2f%2fkidshealth.org%2fkid%2fhtbw%2f/RK=0/RS=y2aW.Onf1Hs6RISRJ9Hye6gXvow-
```

Sure does look like the RV=, RE=, RU=, RK=, RS= values are of the same family. It's just that somewhere the arg concatenation is screwing up on their side.

Comment: [My very related answer on Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/68072/32372)