# RewriteRule for .html/RK=0/RS=[random_string]

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a Joomla 2.5 based website where I am trying to redirect URLs that contain `/RK=0/RS=` with random code at the end.  They cause 404 errors in my server’s access log.  Here are some samples:

```
/blog/name-of-blog-post.html/RK=0/RS=_ep9ZOcaWbdT5g4pr_m9ddy3Rxo-
```

I have found several solutions that do not work for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/RK=0/RS= /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*)/RK=0/RS= /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*)(.html)/RK=0/RS= /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*)(.html)/RK=0/RS=(.*) /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)RK=0/RS= /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)RS=^ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)RK= /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/RK= /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Any ideas on how to code the rewrite to catch and remove the `/RK=0/RS=_ep9ZOcaWbdT5g4pr_m9ddy3Rxo-`
in the example provided?  I have hundreds of these with different random codes at the end of the URLs.

Comment: Did you try: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/RK=0/RS=.+$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]`?

Comment: Thanks for the code; unfortunately, this did not resolve the problem.  I still see the 404 error and there is no redirection.

Comment: Does `/blog/` also have a .htaccess? If yes then post its content in question.

Comment: No, it does not. The /blog/ is not a physical directory on the server. This is a Joomla site and the /blog/ is a menu item.

I don't want this to look like I am promoting my site, but it may help if you see the actual links:

http://www.grapeinc.com/blog/what-is-in-a-brand.html/RK=0/RS=0DcSncLO8tZ153bIsZMnKADfZQw-

http://www.grapeinc.com/blog/what-is-in-a-brand.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite rule remove everything after RK=0/RS=](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761208/htaccess-rewrite-rule-remove-everything-after-rk-0-rs)

Comment: A related one: [Strange entry in access log containing /RS= @ Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/58871/32372)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a Joomla site make sure this is your **very first rule** in the root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/RK=0/RS= /$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: That rewrite rule caused a 500 internal server error; however, I took your advice and move "RewriteRule ^(.*)/RK=0/RS= /$1 [L,NC,R=301]" to directly under the RewriteEngine On and it worked!  THANK YOU!