# What does //RK=0 mean at the end of a URL?

Tags: wordpress

When I check with google index "site:http://example.com" I see a few webpages that have the real page followed by //RK=0.  I have no idea what this means, how it got there, and why Google indexed it.

As a developer, I need to know why anyone would put such a suffix on the end of a URL, because it's nothing I coded for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite rule remove everything after RK=0/RS=](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761208/htaccess-rewrite-rule-remove-everything-after-rk-0-rs)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, I saw that post.  I'm not interested in .htaccess.  I'm asking why the RK=0 even exists?  Where did it come from?  Who uses it?  What does it mean?

Comment: There's some good info in that thread concerning possible sources.

Comment: its only in your logs? = yahoo robot = indexing = good :)

Comment: Didn't look at logs.  As question mentioned, it's from doing SEO analysis and finding link to my web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying DMAN's answer - one of the non-selected answer from: [.htaccess rewrite rule remove everything after RK=0/RS=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761208/htaccess-rewrite-rule-remove-everything-after-rk-0-rs)

Someone found where this mess is coming from.
http://xenforo.com/community/threads/server-logs-with-rk-0-rs-2-i-now-know-what-these-are.73853/

It looks like actually NOT malicious, it's something broken with Yahoo rewrites that create URLs that point to pages that don't exist.
The demo described on xenforo does replicate it, and the pattern of the URLS that Yahoo is producing:

```
http://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=A0SO810GVXBTMyYAHoxLBQx./RV=2/RE=1399899526/RO=10/RU=http%3a%2f%2fkidshealth.org%2fkid%2fhtbw%2f/RK=0/RS=y2aW.Onf1Hs6RISRJ9Hye6gXvow-
```

Sure does look like the RV=, RE=, RU=, RK=, RS= values are of the same family. It's just that somewhere the arg concatenation is screwing up on their side.

Neal additional comment: 
   Maybe at one time there was a bug or something odd going on with Yahoo.  It caused Google to enter these extra URLs into its index.  I am going to remove them with the WebmasterTools "disavow" feature, as Google may be seeing them as duplicate content and thus causing contributing to a "Panda" penalty.